# Which more can I remove from my /boot in order to get space?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I'm using ubuntu (3.13.0-34). I installed it, left 300M for boot, but seems that it was not enough anymore.
I follow some instructions here and removed all older kernels from it.

```
/dev/sda6       277M  212M   52M  81% /boot
/dev/sda9       625G   71G  522G  12% /home
/dev/sda1       496M   28M  469M   6% /boot/efi

cvgaviao@ubuntu-dell:/boot$ ls -l
total 35310
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1162712 Ago 13 13:45 abi-3.13.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165611 Ago 13 13:45 config-3.13.0-34-generic
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Dez 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 Set  5 11:03 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19145757 Set  4 00:16 initrd.img-3.13.0-34-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 Fev 22  2014 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176500 Mar 12 09:31 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178176 Mar 12 09:31 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178680 Mar 12 09:31 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3381262 Ago 13 13:45 System.map-3.13.0-34-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5797728 Ago 13 13:45 vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5799640 Ago 15 15:36 vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic.efi.signed
```

But Software Updater show me this message:

```
The upgrade needs a total of 73,0 M free space on disk '/boot'. 
Please free at least an additional 19,2 M of disk space on '/boot'. 
Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.
```

The strange fact is that it wants to install kernel 3.13.0 (Ubuntu Base)

Is there any file that I could safely remove in order to let software updater to get more space?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Comment: Honestly, with the size of your hard drive, you are making life more difficult by being so stingy with the size of /boot

Comment: Nope, nothing to remove there. You'll need to boot from the DVD/USB, and use Gparted to expand /dev/sda6. ...not really a duplicate, as there are no kernels to be removed.

Comment: ok guys. I'm waiting for an external HD that I ordered to get this done. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @mikewhatever suggested, boot into a live session from CD or USB stick (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) with an up to date Ubuntu iso image and use `gparted` to enlarge the partition which is mounted under `/boot`, i.e. `/dev/sda6` (give some space from `/dev/sda9`). The size of the `/boot` partition has been badly chosen!

BACKUP ALL DATA ON PARTITIONS YOU'RE RESIZING, better the whole disk!